# Empty Span Disappears in CSS3 Flexboxes

Tags: html, angularjs, css, flexbox

I have this html:

```
<div class="panel panel-info">
        <div class="panel-heading">Person</div>
        <div class="panel-body">
          <div class="data">
            <p class="keys">
              <label>Name: </label>
              <label>Family: </label>
            </p>
            <p>
              <span ng-bind="name"></span>
              <span ng-bind="family"></span>
            </p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

.data {
    display: flex;
}
.keys, .values {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    margin: 0;
}
```

For some reason, empty spans behave as display none. I want it to be just empty space. First time it happens to me!

Expected:

Name:

Family: "hey"

Actual:

Name: "hey"

Family:

Comment: sorry, dint get your question..could you please explain a little bit cleearly..

Comment: Also, use id="..." if you want to declare a type, wich is only going to be used once.

Comment: `<span>` is an inline element. Nothing in your css would make it take up any space if it is empty.

Comment: I tried with display block. It doesn't work.

Comment: *"It doesn't work"* doesn't explain what is expected or what actually occurs. Create a simple demo that shows expected results as well as current code

Comment: As you can understand from my example, I want ket value to be value next to key. In this case the value from the second row goes up to first row if tge first row span is empty.

Comment: That's what demo's and descriptions of expected results are for. We don't know what you are looking for

Comment: Your issue is verified in [this DEMO on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hnc20j6m/).

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is verified in [this DEMO on JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hnc20j6m/).

From the Docs:

> ### Flex item considerations
>
> Text that is directly contained inside a flex container is automatically wrapped in an anonymous flex item. However, **an anonymous flex item that contains only white space is not rendered**, as if it were designated `display: none`.

-- [MDN Documentation - Using CSS flexible boxes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Using_CSS_flexible_boxes)

Your problem can be solved by adding a **non-breaking space** to your span.

```
    <p class="values">
      <span ng-bind="name+'&nbsp'"></span>
      <span ng-bind="family">vvv</span>
    </p>
```